# How to get all files containing substring like "abc" in codeingiter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have many files with filenames like "black_abc", "white_abc","black_cde", "white_abc". How can I get only the files with the filename containing "abc"?

Comment: from where directroy? from datbase? and what you have tried

Comment: base_url(). "files/" from this directory

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `strpos()`?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
<?php
 $arr = ["black_abc","white_abc","black_cde","white_abc"];
 foreach($arr as $i => $item) {
   if (strpos($item, '_abc')) {
     echo 'found _abc in ' . $item;
     echo '<br>';
   }
 }
?>
```

Output:

```
found _abc in black_abc
found _abc in white_abc
found _abc in white_abc
```

Comment: I have unlimited files which added dynamically so I cant do like this

Answer (score 0):

Use the [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function like this :

```
<?php
$filename = "absolute path of the directory/*abc*";
foreach (glob($filename) as $filefound) {
    echo "$filefound size " . filesize($filefound) . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: ok got the issue, it should be physical path of directory, updated answer